# What is the reasoning for the integral notation for a functor's category of elements?

Tags: category-theory, notation

Given a functor $F:C\to \mathsf{Set}$, I've seen the integral notation $\int_C F$ from many sources (such as Awodey or Riehl) to indicate its category of elements $\text{el}\ F$. Now, I know that the end of a functor $G: C^\mathsf{op}\times C\to D$ has the same notation, but I cannot see how the extranaturality condition for the functor $G$ is related to the category of elements of a functor like $F$.

So, my questions would be:

1. Is the integral notation due to some extranaturality condition?
2. If not, what is the reason for this specific notation?

Comment: I really like this notation. An integral puts me in mind of summing up many small parts to make a whole, and indeed $F$ (when we deal with presheaves, anyway) is a colimit over $\int F$

Comment: I think of the category of elements as "summing" up $Fc$ for each $c$ to obtain the total space.

Comment: I do think the integral notation is fantastic! It really does get the idea across. It just becomes confusing when (co)ends also possess the same notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of objects of $\int F$ is the disjoint union of the sets $F(A)$ with $A \in \mathcal{C}$. A morphism $(A,a) \to (B,b)$ is a morphism $f : A \to B$ with $b = F(f)(a)$. This exactly gives the following picture, which I included in my category theory textbook (section 5.2). I think it explains the integral sign quite well, namely that $\int F$ is the "area under $F$".

[image]

Comment: How would an element $(A, a')$ for $a\not= a'$ fit into this picture?

Comment: It's on a different height than $(A,a)$. The analogy here is that the set $F(A)$ is replaced by a number, its elements are the numbers below it. I mean when $F$ takes finite sets as values, you can make this quite literally true.

Comment: Ah, I see the analogy now